# Strange description when debugging the datasource of an NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nstableview, nstablerowview

### The context

I have an error with the `datasource` of my `NSTableView`.

The error is

> *** Assertion failure in -[NSTableView _uncachedRectHeightOfRow:],  /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1265.19/TableView.subproj/NSTableView.m:1784

at the line `self.tableView scrollRowToVisible:0] ;`.

### The strange description

When I try to debug this error and type in the debugger

`po [self tableView:self.tableView viewForTableColumn:[self.tableView tableColumns][0] row:0]`

I get

`<NSTableRowView: 0x6000001b7300> - row: -1`.

My question is:

- **What is this `row: -1`?** (I don't see any `row` property in `NSTableRowView`)
- **What kind of hints can this information gives me on the first error?**

Comment: Are you using a delegate as well?  `tableView:heightOfRow` cannot return zero.   It would be a neat way to make rows disappear, but alas.  I mention it because the assertion failure is in `uncachedRectHeightOfRow`.   I guess you could have issues with the row height being zero in recycled cells, too.

Comment: The problem was indeed caused by a 0 height. I am also using a delegate.

Comment: @stevesliva Do you want to make your comment an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a `NSTableViewDelegate` , then `tableView:heightOfRow` *can not* return zero.

It would be a neat way to make rows disappear, but alas. I mention it because the assertion failure is in `-[NSTableView _uncachedRectHeightOfRow:]`.

You might also have issues with the row height being zero in recycled cells.